# Pantalla en blanco

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema para hacer funcionar una sencilla aplicación en angular 10 ya que recién estoy empezando con este framework.

Estoy haciendo una petición HTTP a un servidor en local que únicamente me devuelve un string, pero al intentar acceder desde el componente que creé, la pantalla sale totalmente en blanco, no me marca error por ningún sitio, únicamente da ese problema cuando intento colocar ese componente en la vista. No se a que se pueda deber, ya que otro componente de prueba que tenía también deja de mostrarse, es decir todo lo que hay en la vista desaparece al colocar ese componente, hay alguna razón? probando me di cuenta de que todo ocurre (lo de que desaparezca todo) cuando escribo la siguiente línea.

```
constructor(private holaService: HolaService) { }
```

la cual la tengo dentro de la clase del componente, donde importo el servicio que me proporciona la solicitud en sí. Les agradecería su respuesta

Dejo el código:

este es el componente en si

```
import { importType } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HolaService } from './../../hola.service';

@Component({

    selector: 'holamundo',
    templateUrl: './HolaMundo.component.html'

})

export class HolaMundo {
     

respuesta: any;
constructor(private holaService: HolaService) { }

    getHolaTexto() {
        this.holaService.getHolaMundo().subscribe(
          res => {
            this.respuesta = res;
            res => console.log(res);
          },
          err => console.error(err)
        );
        
    }
}
```

El servicio que utilizo, es este:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HolaService {

  API_URI = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getHolaMundo() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/api/hola`)
  }
}
```

Por último esta es la vista del componente:

```
<div>
    <button (click)="getHolaTexto()">Hola mundo</button>
    <p>Respuesta:</p>
        <p>{{respuesta}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: bienvenido.
Seria bueno que subieras el código de tus componentes y el del servicio, ya que sin eso es difícil ayudar. Revisa tu consola probablemente te falten algunas importaciones. Por ejemplo para peticiones http necesitas importar en tu app.module.ts HttpClientModule.
Otra podría ser que este colocando el html con una condición que no se cumpla.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás usando el componente? ¿Tienes otro componente que sea el "main" (el que llama a `<holamundo>`?

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos! no sabía lo amable que era esta comunidad. Solucione mi problema, como dijo @UrielManzano creo el problema recaía en unos unos imports que no tenía en el app.module.ts. Pese a todo era algo raro por que ni el inspector de código de los navegadores ni en la consola del mismo me marcaba problema alguno. El constructor lo deje como estaba así que supongo que era un problema concatenado. Gracias a todos de nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser algo muy simple, me ha sucedido en muy raras ocasiones, creo que tu problema es de puntuación, bueno, puedes intentarlo y me comentas.

Ya que el error te sale al tratar de inyectar el Servicio en tu componente, el error está en tu Servicio, y que falta en tu servicio? pues punto y coma, no siempre los punto y coma dan error en TypeScript, pero a veces son molestos y sí da error no deja inyectar los servicios.

Completa los Punto y Coma:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; // <-- ACÁ!

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HolaService {

  API_URI = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getHolaMundo() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/api/hola`); // <-- ACÁ!
  }
}
```

Adicionalmente puedes probar agregar el tipo de retorno de tu función **getHolaMundo(): Observable< any>** si aún continuas teniendo el mismo problema.

Comment: Ese punto y coma es opcional, Javascript/Typescript puede causar comportamientos inesperados cuando el código tiene una interpretación ambigua por la falta de punto y coma, pero no es el caso.

Comment: @PabloLozano vi tu comentario, el joven indica que al colocar el constructor `constructor(private holaService: HolaService) { }` lo cual se entiende que su problema está en la inyección del Servicio HolaService en el Constructor del Componente, sí retira el parámetro puede volver a ver la vista.
Y revisando el Servicio, pues sí tienes razón esos punto y coma no deberían generar comportamientos inesperado.

Comment: gracias, casi me da un paro cardiaco. se veia mi front en blanco y mi error también estaba en el servicio